# Opening specific Excel sheet with Python when opening application

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Is there a way to specify which sheet to open within an excel workbook when using a python command to open the application? (ex: using win32 Dispatch or os.system)?

Comment: Do you want to open only 1 sheet or the entire workbook with focus on 1 sheet?

Comment: The entire workbook with focus on 1 sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to activate the focus on the sheet first, then open the workbook.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('my_workbook.xlsx')
sheet_to_focus = 'my_sheet'

for s in range(len(wb.sheetnames)):
    if wb.sheetnames[s] == sheet_to_focus:
        break
wb.active = s

wb.save('my_workbook.xlsx')
```

Then you could probably open it (untested code):

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\\my_folder\\subfolder')
os.system('start excel.exe my_workbook.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to open excel to view this specific sheet? using something similar? does openpyxl have a viewer?

Comment: When opening the excel book using the os.system, tab 1 is still opening as opposed to "tab3" which is the one I need opened, even after adding the openpyxl code in the post, is this working for you?

Comment: there was a typo. Could you try again using the code? Works for me

Comment: apologies, I already found this!. What I am asking about specifically is when you run os.system. When you run os.system, the default sheet in excel that opens is sheet1.  Assuming there are multiple sheets in the workbook, I need it so that the sheet it opens to sheet 3, not sheet 1

Comment: Is it working when you open it by hand? For me, it does

Comment: Could you consider upvoting/accepting so that other people could find this answer aswell?

Comment: I tried, but this is my first question and I dont have enough reputation to upvote, once I get the points I will! Apologies for this!

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to be with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path/to/sheet.xlsx', 'sheet_name')
```

You can read the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html